# Symfony User Roles not selected in user form

Tags: php, symfony, user-roles

I have created a simple user/role form. The form shows the user's detail correctly and displays all the possible roles, but for some reason it does not pre-select the users' current role. For the relationship between the user and role I had the following in the user entity class:

```
/** 
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist","remove"}) 
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role") 
*/ 
protected $roles;
```

The formtype class was built using:

```
$builder->add('firstname')
->add('lastname')
->add('email')
->add('roles');
```

The database looks like this:
[image]

Any hints/assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you link the `User` object to the `FormBuilder`? Like this:  
 `createForm(new UserType(), $user);`

Comment: Yes I do, in my controller I have:
`$user = $userRepo->findOneById( $userId );
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);`

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your roles fields as entity
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html
change this line `->add('roles');` to:

```
->add('roles', 'entity', array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'property' => 'name',
                'class'    => 'Your_Path\Entity\Roles',
        ));
```

it should work.

### Second option:

you can try to create role type form as mentioned [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) and then do something like this

```
$builder->add('roles', 'collection', array('type' => new RoleType()));
```

its recomended to read this [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) about `mapped` option and other as `by_reference`

Comment: Thanks, I also tried that and I'm still not getting the roles pre-selected.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in symfony4, adding this did the trick for me:

```
'choice_value' => function ($choice) {
    return $choice;
},
```